# Как сделать открытую БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, сеть, entity-framework-core

Как мне сделать открытую Базу данных,  чтобы к ней можно было подключиться через интернет с другого компа, использую EF core(если это вообще возможно)? Т.е. у меня есть БД на одном компе, а на другом программа, использующая ef core, которая подключается к БД и берет от туда данные.  Если все таки возможно это реализовать, используя EF core, то скажите, что мне писать в строке подключения в методе OnConfiguring и как это вообще сделать. И будет ли   использование здесь Ef core   костылем?
Я до этого с БД, считай, никогда не работал, т.е. я даже sql не знаю

Comment: Недопустимый костыль - это даже думать прокинуть базу данных по сети.... в реальной жизни за такое серьезно могут наказать, это не безопасно от слова совсем. Хотя такое конечно возможно. Ставите например MSSQL или любую другую сетевую СУБД, прокидываете ее порт на внешку и вперед костылить) строка подключения будет та же, только вместо localhost или локального IP пропишите внешний IP и порт

Comment: а как мне лучше сделать. Просто хочу сделать что-то подобия диска

Comment: Я не знаю сути вашей задачи, но обычно база данных расположена за неким сервисом, который реализует API. Вот это API уже торчит наружу и общается с внешним миром.

Comment: Обычное консольное приложение(мне лень делать интерфейс), с помощью которого можно по сети получить файл, который храниться на БД или загрузить по сети на БД

Comment: Здесь EF core не будет костылем, так как оно вообще не поможет решить задачу. Вам нужно поднять что-то вроде IPSec VPN на компьютере, где установлен сервер с БД, а на клиентах подключаться к этому VPN. Тогда у вас схема будет аналогична локальной сети.